# Customizing AddThis Share Menu for iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, addthis

Any body knows how to customize AddThis ShareMenu compact view to add additional option like linkedIn.And I also have another problem regarding size of Tumblr and Delicious in iphone .
It is working perfect in ipad and in iphone,the size of Tumblr and Delicious view expands the size of iphone.

[AddThis Reference](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide)

Comment: Could you explain better your question? What/Where 'addthis' menu are you referring too?

Comment: I have given a link named "AddThis Reference" below the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st problem I have solved by using simple api method that is given below**

```
[AddThisSDK setFavoriteMenuServices:@"facebook",@"twitter",@"linkedin",@"delicious",@"tumblr",nil];
```

**and another problem is remaining that is to adjust size of tumblr,delicious and linkedIn view according to iphone.It's size is according to ipad not iphone.**